# mysql remote connection on Amazon ec2 ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, amazon-ec2

I installed a MySQL server in an Amazon EC2 instance. Then, I made the following changes in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
#skip-external-locking
```

After restarting the server, I executed the following statements on my database:

```
GRANT ALL ON MyDB.* TO newuser@'x.x.x.x' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

where x.x.x.x is the public IP of my client machine.

On the machine which is running MySQL server, I have created the proper security group (i.e., TCP only), and added a rule to allow MySQL from the inbound tab of the security group.

I can connect to this instance via SSH with a key.

Is it possible to make a connection to the MySQL server from any machine using the SSH key?